# Fubini theorem related proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus

Let $C={x,y; x>0,y>0}$ and $f(x,y)=1/(x^2+\sqrt x)(y^2+\sqrt y)$. I need to show that $f$ is integrable over $C$. My idea was to set up a rectifiable set $C_N=(1,N)$ and then use Fubini theorem, then I would see whether the et is integrable or not. However, while integrating the function, it becomes a mess and does not clarify anything. Can someone please show me a way to do it? A small hint would do about how to proceed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't that function continuous?

Comment: @Devilathor yes it is

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice we are talking about improper integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remember that to prove that a function is integrable you don't need to calculate the integral itself; it is enough to show that the absolute of the function is dominated by an integrable function (and to show that the function is measurable).

Now note that $f$ is non-negative and measurable (because $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$ with $g$ and $h$ measurable). Then Fubinis theorem yields
$$
\int_{(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)} f(x,y) dxdy = \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt{x}} dx \int_{(0,\infty)} \frac{1}{y^2+\sqrt{y}} dy = \left( \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt{x}} dx \right)^2.
$$
To prove that the rightmost improper integral is finite you should investigate $\int_0^1$ and $\int_1^\infty$ separately.